# How to clear WebView video cache after reload?

Tags: android, webview

Helo!
I have found nearly every answer I could found, but no one worked.
I want to clear the video cache after I reload WebView, which means after reload, the WebView should fetch the video again from the website.But I found after reload, the WebView always use the cached video. The Code like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.web_view)
        val url =
            "https://m.baidu.com/video/page?pd=video_page&nid=6270338152584307222&sign=18044240099190369598&word=%E3%80%8A%E6%88%91%E6%9B%BE%E7%94%A8%E5%BF%83%E7%88%B1%E7%9D%80%E4%BD%A0%E3%80%8B%E5%BD%93%E5%BF%A7%E4%BC%A4%E7%9A%84%E6%97%8B%E5%BE%8B%E5%93%8D%E8%B5%B7%EF%BC%8C%E6%98%AF%E5%90%A6%E5%94%A4%E8%B5%B7%E6%88%91%E4%BB%AC%E9%81%97%E5%BF%98%E7%9A%84%E8%AE%B0%E5%BF%86&oword=%E8%B0%AD%E5%92%8F%E9%BA%9F&atn=index&frsrcid=5373&ext=%7B%22jsy%22%3A1%7D&top=%7B%22sfhs%22%3A1%2C%22_hold%22%3A2%7D&sl=4&lid=9667438968531841346&fr0=A&fr1=C&_t=1656822206409&bk=1&_t=1656826154699"

        webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                view: WebView?,
                request: WebResourceRequest?
            ): Boolean {
                return !request?.url.toString().startsWith("http")

            }
        }

        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

        webView.settings.mixedContentMode = WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW
        webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        webView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
        webView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
        webView.settings.builtInZoomControls = true
        webView.settings.displayZoomControls = false
        webView.settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE;
        webView.loadUrl(url)

        findViewById<SwipeRefreshLayout>(R.id.pullToRefresh).apply {
            setOnRefreshListener {
                
                webView.clearCache(true)
                webView.reload()

                isRefreshing = false
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Because the video component on the page has a loading progress bar, I can easily find out if the video is redownloading after a reload.
I've tried delete the $context.cacheDir and it's parent dir, but it doesn't work at all.

Please help me, thank you very much

Comment: Check this question: 2465432

Comment: I've tried this method on this page provided, but it don't work for me .